# iTerm2 slide down over full screen app

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, iterm2

I always have my IDE (phpStorm) in full screen mode (Yosemite).

I want my iTerm2 hotkey to slide my terminal window down over the IDE, so it doesn't open up a new space for the terminal window. As once the window slides back up it leaves me on an empty space, rather than going back to phpStorm.

Comment: I've since switched over to https://hyper.is/ which allows this.

Comment: how did you enable the feature in hyper?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> **Attention**! See Update3 for new iTerm versions (works for 2.1.5)

## Original Answer

This command allows iTerm to work over fullscreen apps

```
defaults write ~/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Info LSUIElement true
```

But it hides iTerm's context menu. To access iTerm's preferences, right-click on the tabs bar and select the proper menu item; or focus on any iTerm's window and press <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd>.

## Update

> If you use the beta version of iTerm, there is no need to run the previous command. You can turn on *Preferences > Advanced > Hide iTerm2 from the dock and from the <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> app switcher*.
>
> Also make sure that the profile you use for the dropdown window (*Hotkey window* by default) is allowed on all spaces (*Preferences > Profiles > "Hotkey window" profile > "Window" tab > Space: "all spaces"*).
>
> Remember to restart iTerm2.

## Update 2

> If you can't find *Preferences*, use the shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>Right Click</kbd> in an open iTerm2 terminal window, then select *"Edit Session"*.

## Update 3

> In 2.1.5, you should use the *"Exclude from Dock and ⌘-Tab Application Switcher"* option in *Preferences -> Appearance*. When iTerm2 is excluded from the dock, you can always get back to the Preferences window using the status bar item, or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd>. Look for an iTerm2 icon on the right side of your menu bar.
>
> [image: Activate]

## Update 4

In v.3.4.15, you should follow the comment from @Sudhi. Profiles -> specific Profile -> Keys -> "A hotkey opens dedicated window with this profile" and configure hotkey.[image: v3.4 config window screen]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please clarify how to access the Preferences? Specifically what should be right clicked?

Comment: Right click anywhere in opened iterm's terminal, select 'edit session'

Comment: this solution works but in my case only for the main screen. is there a fix available?

Comment: This works, but it severely reduces the utility of non-hotkey windows since you can't `Cmd-Tab` to them.

Comment: To amend my previous comment, this is now possible WITHOUT hiding iTerm from ⌘-Tab in the iTerm2 v3 beta (iTerm3?).

Comment: I can't find the preference in the iterm2 3.1.beta.5 build (i.e. _Preferences > Advanced > Hide iTerm2 from the dock and ..._ ). Is the preference renamed? I also couldn't find a default value for the preference from command line. For example `defaults read /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Info LSUIElement` returns `The domain/default pair of (/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Info, LSUIElement) does not exist` Note that my iTerm.app lives in `/Applications` and not in `~/Applications`. And changing the location to `~/Applications/..` still gives `does not exist` value

Comment: @Friendka thanks, I can navigate to preference window just fine (i.e. I can see _ Preferences > Advanced_ ). However, when I search "hide" or scroll through all the available preferences, I don't see the preference item that you have mentioned. That is why I tried to see the value by calling `defaults read ...` from command line.

Comment: After digging through the preferences for a while, I found it in _Preferences > Select Hotkey Profile on the left column > Keys > Hotkey Window_ (this will be checked for the Hotkey Window profile) _> Configure Hotkey Window > select Floating Window_ . I am on macOS with iterm2 version `3.1.beta.5`. You may want to update your answer again :)

Comment: After setting "Floating window" don't forget to completely restart iterm2 (cmd-Q).

Comment: It seems this chained again. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-WIHGY_mrk) helped me out this time.

Answer (score 35):

As state [in another stackexchange answer for the same question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/445147/221910)

**TLDR** [watch a video I created](https://youtu.be/iSXZufjt5DI)

## Step 1 HotKey

Create Dedicated Hotkey Window

`Preferences` > `Keys` > Click `Create Dedicated Hotkey Window`

set hot key by pressing `Click to Set` (and subsequently your desired key combo)

## Step 2 Floating in Focus

Make the app stay above any apps that are currently in the workspace and maintain focus (in the same dialog from above)

- Check `Pin hotkey window(stays open on loss of keyboard focus)`
- Check `Floating window`

## Step 3 Looks

When creating the hotkey terminal a new profile is created (generally named "Hotkey Window"), update profile as desired

### OTHER NOTES

- To enable some changes you will need to restart iTerm
- You will be using a specific hot key to call up the overlay
- You may also want to access preferences as well, `command`-`,`
- if using an older version of iTerm [here is the previous video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-WIHGY_mrk)
- if using an even older version of iTerm [here is the pre-previous video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjKVHsp9e0o)

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful walk through. Even if this is not possible anymore you did a great job

Comment: @fmquaglia Updated the video and the description, it should still be possible (if not easier)

Comment: The image for this setting is here: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/1570#note_20905518

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to propose an variant of [Marc's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45625584/48136). And [Friedka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37407851/48136) is not anymore up to date, some options were removed, some changed, I'm using iTerm `Build 3.2.0beta4`.

1. **Create and assign a hotkey**

   `Preferences` > `Keys` > Click `Create Dedicated Hotkey Window`

   1. Follow the instructions to set the hot key.
   2. Check *pin hotkey window* and *floating window*
2. **Create a window arrangement**

   That's where my answer differ, Marc's answer rely on making iTerm to start with hotkey profile per default, which may be cumbersome if you need a simple standard window. Instead this answer proposes to use iterm's window arrangement.

   1. So open a hotkey window
   2. Make sure all window with another profile (usually named *Default*) are closed. The only remaining active (hidden or not) window should be the Hotkey window.
   3. Save the arrangement, `Window` > `Save Window Arrangement`
   4. Make sure this arrangement is the default

      `Preferences` > `Arrangements` > Select the arrangement and click `Set Default`
   5. In the preference, make iterm starts with the default arrangement. :

      `Preferences` > `General` > `Startup` > Select `Open Default Window Arrangement`
3. Optionally tweak the hotkey window appearance

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible, unfortunately. See discussions [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/iterm2-discuss/hotkey$20fullscreen%7Csort:date/iterm2-discuss/MXFWW-m0_Po/hDlyi-zfEEwJ) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/iterm2-discuss/hotkey/iterm2-discuss/ECQl7oBy3a4/yUawv6udMcIJ). Apps like Quicksilver, Alfred, and Dash are able to do it, so it is *technically* possible - just not implemented by George. It may become a moot point for these use cases when we get [El Capitan's Split View](http://appleinsider.com/articles/15/06/15/first-look-os-x-el-capitans-split-view-and-mission-control)

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question or this answer might just be outdated, but I believe it is *now* possible.

Comment: @Marc Yes, it is now possible.

Answer (score 0):

**try my setting.
it works for me.**

to screen capture:

[1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3nAY.png

[2]https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ89k.png

[3]https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqoIw.png