# iTerm as visor with shadow

Tags: iterm

does anybody know how can I show a shadow also if I have the iTerm window on top like the visor from Totalterminal.
I have added an border but this is not enough contrast to see the window endig.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iTerm2 slide down over full screen app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456472/iterm2-slide-down-over-full-screen-app)

Comment: It is not a duplicate because I ask specific to a shadow if iTerm is on fullscreen.